# MSI for tkinter app created using cx_freeze not working

Tags: tkinter, beautifulsoup, windows-installer, cx-freeze

I am creating a python app using Tkinter in which I have used the beautifulsoup and googlesearch libraries. The `setup.py` of the app is as follows:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("subd.py", base=base, icon = "icon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "SubD",
    author = "Mayank",
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages":["tkinter","bs4","googlesearch","requests","os"], "include_files":["icon.ico"]}},
    version = "2.1",
    description = "Subtitle Downloader",
    executables = executables
)
```

In the python code `main.py` I am using the `search()` function (of the `googlesearch` library) as follows -

```
import googlesearch as gs
...
for j in gs.search(q, tld="com", num=10, stop=1, pause=3):
    sp = "https://subscene.com/subtitles/"
    n = len(sp)
    if j[:n] == sp:
        possible.append(j)
```

The executable of this code created using -

```
python setup.py build
```

is working fine. But when I create an MSI for this using -

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

The `search()` function of the `googlesearch` library does not seem to be working.
Although, if instead of installing through the MSI on a new PC, I copy the `build` folder to the new PC and directly run, it still works fine.
Also, the MSI is working fine in my PC, maybe, because I have all the necessary libraries installed.
Kindly explain why is it happening and how can I fix this, it'll be a great help.

Thank You